# Как происходит сравнение строк?

Tags: файлы, строки

Код проверки отсортированности файла со строками

Как происходит сравнение строк? ( по длине, по символам?)

```
var
   inputf, s, s1:string;
   input:textfile;

begin

   AssignFile(input, inputf);

   reset(input);

   if (not EOF(input)) then

      readln(input, s);

   while (not EOF(input)) do

   begin

      s1 := s;

      readln(input, s);

      if (s1 > s) then

      begin

         ShowMessage('Файл не отсортирован');

         exit;

      end;
   end;
```

Comment: @bob, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

Сравнение идет по коду символа.

> При сравнении строки рассматриваются посимвольно слева направо, при этом сравниваются коды соответствующих пар символов. Строки равны, если они имеют одинаковую длину и посимвольно эквивалентны. В строках разной длины существующий символ всегда больше соответствующего ему отсутствующего символа. Меньшей будет та строка, у которой меньше код первого несовпадающего символа (вне зависимости от максимальных и текущих длин сравниваемых строк).

```
'abc' > 'ab' (true)
'abc' = 'abc' (true)
'abc' < 'abc ' (false)
```